# SqlDataSource control is hidden in ToolBox of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, sqldatasource, toolbox

I'm a fresher started my career with SharePoint. I created a visual web part and tried to bind data with grid view of a SqlDataSource. But I cant see the SqlDataSource control in the toolbox and its hidden. I can see its being disabled when I clicked "Show All". I tried deleting .tbd files and resetting thing as many people suggested and all. Still I'm struggling with it. Can anyone help me out with it.